# Inner product at the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, inner-products

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set with nonempty interior, i.e. $K^{\circ}\neq \emptyset$. Suppose there exist a nonzero vector $v$ such that

$$\langle x, v\rangle\geq 0$$

for all $x\in K^{\circ}$. I want to show that in this case the property holds for all  $x\in K$.

It is supposed to be a continuity argument. Am having trouble because $x\in K\setminus K^{\circ}$ doesn't imply that there exist a sequence in $K^{\circ}$ converging to $x$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There does exist a sequence in $K^{0}$ converging to $x$. This is a property of convex sets with non-empty interior  in $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But $x \in K \setminus K^\circ$ *does* imply that there exists a sequence in $K^\circ$ converging to $x$.

Choose any open ball $B \subset K^\circ$ centered at $p$.

Let $\overline{ab}$ be the diameter of $B$ perpendicular to the segment $\overline{xp}$.

The interior of the entire triangle $\triangle xab$ is therefore contained in $K^\circ$, and in particular the half-open segment $[p,x)$ is contained in $K^\circ$.

Comment: I see. So I can take any sequence $(\lambda_n)\subset [0,1)$ such that $\lambda_n \to 1$ and let $x_n=\lambda_n x + (1-\lambda_n)p$. Then $(x_n)\subset K^\circ$ and $x_n \to x$. So by continuity of the inner product I conclude that $\langle x, v\rangle\geq 0$. Correct?

Comment: That looks good.